# foreach loop get index of an object?

Tags: php

I currently have the following object in php:

```
  "Direction": "Please choose the direction"
  "Media": "Please choose the stock"
  "Coating": "Please choose the coating"
```

I then loop through it with a foreach

```
foreach ($product as $key => $att) {
// is there away I can get the index?  Meaning 0, 1, etc?
}
```

In the foreach is there away I can get the index?  I need a numerical index value.

Comment: If you don't need the current assoc key, you can do `foreach (array_values($product) as $key => $value)` and $key should now be numeric. Otherwise you'll just need to create your own counter and increment it as you loop through them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```php
$i = 0;
foreach ($product as $key => $att) {
    echo "index is: $i<br>";
    $i++;
}
```